# Как создать кастомный шоткат для unity editor, который будет по сочетанию клавиш создавать активной папке проекта файл Assembly Definition?

Tags: c#, unity3d, assembly, unity3d-editor

Как создать кастомный шоткат для unity editor, который будет по сочетанию клавиш создавать активной папке проекта файл Assembly Definition ?

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужен атрибут [MenuItem](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MenuItem.html). А что он будет делать уже в теле метода реализацию напишете)